# Get last dirname/filename in a file path argument in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, svn

I'm trying to write a post-commit hook for SVN, which is hosted on our development server.  My goal is to try to automatically checkout a copy of the committed project to the directory where it is hosted on the server.  However I need to be able to read only the last directory in the directory string passed to the script in order to checkout to the same sub-directory where our projects are hosted.

For example if I make an SVN commit to the project "example", my script gets "/usr/local/svn/repos/example" as its first argument.  I need to get just "example" off the end of the string and then concat it with another string so I can checkout to "/server/root/example" and see the changes live immediately.

Answer (score 513, accepted):

[`basename`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/basename) does remove the directory prefix of a path:

```
$ basename /usr/local/svn/repos/example
example
$ echo "/server/root/$(basename /usr/local/svn/repos/example)"
/server/root/example
```

Comment: basename is definitely what I'm looking for.  How can get the basename of an argument stored into a variable though?   E.g. `SUBDIR="/path/to/whatever/$(basename $1)"`

Comment: @tj111: sounds like is no `$1`, or `$1` is empty

Comment: unfortunately, if you wrap commands, basename is not a good idea. just something to keep in mind

Answer (score 156):

The following approach can be used to get any path of a pathname:

```
some_path=a/b/c
echo $(basename $some_path)
echo $(basename $(dirname $some_path))
echo $(basename $(dirname $(dirname $some_path)))
```

Output:

```
c
b
a
```

Comment: does not work with paths that have spaces... you can overcome that with quotes... which somehow works `echo "$(basename "$(dirname "$pathname")")"`

Comment: How to print only path /a/b? please?

Answer (score 99):

Bash can get the last part of a path without having to call the external `basename`:

```
dir="/path/to/whatever/"
dir="${dir%/}"             # strip trailing slash (if any)
subdir="${dir##*/}"
```

This uses Bash's parameter expansion to remove the part of the string before the last (remaining) slash.

Comment: On my Mac, using substring notation is more than order of magnitude faster than dirname / basename for the case where you're doing something trivial to each of a few thousand files.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson **Thanks** a lot for **sharing**. _For any future readers who start to wonder **why it is not working** or I am the only stupid out here_ . Above answer assumes that `$1` contains `the path from which last component is to be taken out`. I missed that part. My use case: `target_path='/home/user/dir1/dir2/dir3/'; target_path="${target_path%/}"; last_component=${target_path##*/}; echo $last_component` - Works 

Comment: See here for an explanation of *how* and *why* `${1##*/}` works: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171786/15070

Comment: Thank you, this is **much faster** than `basename`.

Answer (score 2):

To print the file name without using external commands,

Run:

```
fileNameWithFullPath="${fileNameWithFullPath%/}";
echo "${fileNameWithFullPath##*/}" # print the file name
```

This command must run faster than `basename` and `dirname`.

Comment: How is it different from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3294514/ given in 2010?

Answer (score -1):

If the file is in the current directory, you will invite this short:

```
cd /dev/shm
basename $(pwd) # shm
```

I already have had this sed command, although I admit it is not much practical:

```
path="/dev/shm"
sed -r "s/^.*\/(.*)$/\1/" <<< $path # shm
```