# bash convert w/ copying filename

Tags: linux, bash, filenames

I use linux, bash.
I have a bunch of image files in several directories. All have specific names that must be saved (filenames AND directories). But I need to convert all images to different size and ppi. I used the 
`convert -units PixelsPerInch 75 -resize 200x200 ~/filepath/*.jpg ~/filepath.*jpg`
but it replaced the wrong file. Also I've tried 
`"{}" "{}"%03d.jpg`
to add a number to the new filename but it gives only 001.jpg etc.
Solutions like 
[Bash - get last dirname/filename in a file path argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294072/bash-get-last-dirname-filename-in-a-file-path-argument)
or
[Extract filename and extension in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash)
with `${filename%.}` and other parts of scripts
or
http://bytebar.blogspot.com/2008/08/bash-filename-extraction.html
do not work or I have no such knowledge to understand the code...
How can I convert those files keeping their names and directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ls ~/filepath.*jpg | xargs -n 1 -I{} convert -units PixelsPerInch 75 -resize 200x200 {} {}
```

"xargs -n 1" calls the following function with provided arguments one at a time.
The -I{} argument of xargs, tells xargs to replace each occurence of {} with the given argument.

Comment: sorry, it did work! Thank you! The code i used was exactly like in your suggestion.