# A fast and proper way to get the basename of a directory or a file in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, substitution, basename

I have this code:

```bash
get_base() { echo "${1##*/}"; }
```

And this works fine until we have 1 or more
trailing slashes

I have found a solution on how to fix it, but the
problem is that we'll need `extglob` enabled, and I don't
want that:

```bash
ari@ari-gentoo ~ % x='/home/ari///'

ari@ari-gentoo ~ % echo "${x%%+(/)}"
/home/ari
```

Then we can obv save it into a tmp var and run the basename
substitution on it

Anyway, my question is, is there any proper way to do it
and it still being fast (meaning no calls to external commands
because this function gets called quite a lot) without
needing any fancy features enabled?

Thanks for the answers in advance :)

### Questions and answers

- Does [Get last dirname/filename in a file path argument in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294072/get-last-dirname-filename-in-a-file-path-argument-in-bash) answer your question?

> no as all of those solutions either use commands or have a substitution expression that only strips the last slash, not multiples :) (e.g. /home/ari/// with expr ${x%/} would become only /home/ari// when it needs to be /home/ari)

- What do you mean by 'proper'

> By proper I mean 'achieved without enabling extglob or any other fancy features'

Comment: So your question is if that same result can be achieved without using extglob? "Proper" is a vague term.

Comment: @KamilCuk yep, sorry for being vague

Comment: @KamilCuk I added it to the question :)

Comment: Well, `[[ $1 ~ ([^/]*)/*$ ]]; echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`

Comment: @KamilCuk o, interesting, let me see

Comment: But.. also why not just set extglob?

Comment: @KamilCuk It gives me a syntax error, even shellcheck is screaming: SC1009, SC1073 and SC1072

Comment: @KamilCuk I just don't want to depend on extglob if possible

Comment: (+ doesn't `extglob` slow things down? this script even though it's a script needs performance, as much as it can get @KamilCuk)

Comment: @Ari157 Since you're so concerned about performance, have you measured the difference? Also, you could probably write whatever you are doing in a compiled language to boost the overall performance a lot.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have, the current solution is ~0.021 ms slower, and I need to do it in BASH because I am making a plugin manager and am concerened about speed because well... I don't want people to wait for like 10s for all of their plugins to load :)

Comment: If I could I'd do it in C, but I don't think BASH even supports any way to do the same things as `source` can

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get last dirname/filename in a file path argument in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294072/get-last-dirname-filename-in-a-file-path-argument-in-bash)

Comment: @tink no as all of those solutions either use commands or have a substitution expression that only strips the last slash, not multiples :) (e.g. `/home/ari///` with expr `${x%/}` would become only `/home/ari//` when it needs to be `/home/ari`)

Comment: What does _"I don't think BASH even supports any way to do the same things as `source` can"_ mean?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Okay, let's say I want to load an alias into bash, I don't think there's a proper way to do that in C, but when you source some BASH file it can be easily done

Comment: @TedLyngmo you got me thinking right now, I could make a program to generate the lines of bash that need to be ran in C and then run them !

Comment: @TedLyngmo How good of an idea do you think generating the commands in C and then just running them would be? Maybe some caching too ?

Comment: If you're comfortable with C, why not write the whole thing in C? Why does it have to generate bash commands?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I am quite comfy with C, but I don't think C can for example set aliases in BASH and stuff :)

Comment: Ok, that's what you meant by `source`. So the script in question is to be `source`d? No, in that case I guess generating the output to be sourced is an option. Perhaps even using an evil eval: `eval "$(the_c_program)"`

Comment: @TedLyngmo I meant `source loader.sh`, it just has a bunch of functions which set up the env variables, bash functions, aliases, etc. and when I'll make that program it's just gonna be `$(the_c_program)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248846/discussion-between-ari157-and-ted-lyngmo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ### A fast and proper way to get ... in bash

In complement to [oguz ismail's correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74089965/1765658) I would like to suggest use of `-v` flag for this kind of function, in order to reduce forks:

```bash
get_base() {
    if [[ $1 == -v ]] ;then
        local -n _res=$2
        shift 2
    else
        local _res
    fi
    set -- "${1%"${1##*[!/]}"}"
    printf -v _res %s "${1##*/}"
    [[ ${_res@A} == _res=* ]] && echo "$_res"
}
```

This let you try this function by

```
$ get_base /path/entry////
entry
```

But for storing result into some variable, you would **avoid useless fork** like

> ```
> myvar=$(get_base /path/entry////)
> ```

and use prefered syntax:

```
$ get_base -v myvar /path/entry////
$ echo $myvar
entry
```

#### To become a function to *split* `entry` and `path`:

```bash
get_base() {
    if [[ $1 == -v ]] ;then
        local -n _res=$2
        shift 2
    else
        local _res
    fi
    set -- "${1%"${1##*[!/]}"}"
    printf -v _res %s "${1##*/}"
    [[ ${_res@A} == _res=* ]] &&
        echo "$_res" "${1%/$_res}" && return
    printf -v _res[1] %s "${1%/$_res}"
}
```

Then:

```
$ get_base /path/to/entry////
entry /path/to
```

and

```
$ get_base -v myvar /path/to/entry////
$ declare -p myvar 
declare -a myvar=([0]="entry" [1]="/path/to")
$ echo ${myvar[0]}
entry
$ echo ${myvar[1]}
/path/to
```

With spaced unicode filenames:

```
$ get_base -v myvar '/path/to/some dir/some loved file ♥♥♥.xtns'
$ declare -p myvar 
declare -a myvar=([0]="some loved file ♥♥♥.xtns" [1]="/path/to/some dir")
```

Comment: Thank you, this improved my performance by 50%!

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way:

```
get_base() {
  set -- "${1%"${1##*[!/]}"}"
  printf '%s\n' "${1##*/}"
}
```

```
$ get_base /home/oguz//
oguz
$ get_base /root
root
$ get_base /

$ get_base .bash_history
.bash_history
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideas:

```
get_base() { [[ $1 =~ ([^/]*)/*$ ]]; echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; };
get_base() { while [[ "${1%/}" != "$1" ]]; do set -- "${1%%/}"; done; echo "${1##*/}"; }
```